# java class initialization explanation

Tags: java

I kind of new to java and will be happy if anybody could explain the following code samples to me.This is just a sample java code snippet for illustration. But the main question is that if the class Learn initializes another class Smart with a parameter which is also a class Object , then the addition of the dot class to the class Object Sample is kind of confusing to me. Any explanation will be appreciated. I apologize if it is a basic question. thanks.

```
class Learn {
//some codes 
Smart smart = new Smart(Sample.class);
//some codes
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Sample` is the name of a class.  It is *not* an object.  A `new Sample()` is an object whose class is `Sample`.  `Sample.class` is an object whose class is `java.lang.Class` which describes the class `Sample`.

Comment: Straightforward explanation without too much blabla. +1

Comment: thanks for the correction , but then if i may ask further how different is Sample.class from an initialization like              Sample sample = new Sample()

Answer (score 0):

I will break your example in the following way....

**Learn -** is a `Class`

**smart -** is an `Object Reference Variable` of type `Smart`, we can say that Class Learn has a reference of type Smart.

**Sample.class -** Is a way of getting the `Class<T>` for a particular type.

**Extract from Java Docs.**

`During implementation it depends on the Targeting bytecode version. If -target 1.4 (or` `below), a call to Class.forName() is inserted into your code in a static method which is` `called during type initialization. If you use -target 1.5 (or above) the constant pool` `gets a "class" entry`

Please refer **section 15.8.2 of the Java Language Specification** for more details

Answer (score 0):

1. In java, there is a class called "Class" that represent classes and interfaces.
2. There are several ways to get an instance of class "Class". Please take a look at java.lang.Class document.

   - Class.forName(String className)
   - obj.getClass() -obj is any class instance
   - Sample.class  -Sample is a class
3. You are using the 3rd method to get an instance of class "Sample".